# AWS RDS: How do I enable connection for specific IP address?

Tags: amazon-rds, aws

I've been managing a site for over four years, and initially what I did to allow access to the database for some IP address was just editing an existing Security Group called `specificip`

This is what I see when trying to modify the instance of the database:
[image]

The last time I had to make that change was in march (six months ago). Now I'm trying to do it again but I cannot find a way to edit that Security Group. I tried Googling about it and I ended up here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDBInstance.html

And found this:

> **DBSecurityGroups.DBSecurityGroupName.N**
>
> A list of DB security groups to associate with this DB instance.
>
> This setting applies to the **legacy EC2-Classic platform**, which is **no longer used to create new DB instances**. Use the VpcSecurityGroupIds setting instead.

So I Googled a little more and found the "new" VPC Management Console:
https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home?region=us-east-1#SecurityGroups:

Which lists a lot of groups, but not the one I care about. I tried to create a new group there, but I'm not able to find a way to link it to the database

And that's pretty much it. I've been looking for hours, and I'm so sad about it I'm even contemplating moving the service to another place :(

Comment: Perhaps you could consider contacting AWS support, since you're apparently paying for it. I suspect they could be more familiar with their own services than random people on the internet.

Comment: Did you try xing out the one two three four filters? Did you go to the RDS instance itself and look for its security group there?

Comment: @mustaccio Yes, I could, but we're in the "Basic support plan", which means we don't have support. Woah, are you Sherlock Holmes? How smart. But since I can't contact them I'm stuck with trying to ask random people on the internet or changing providers

Comment: @BobbyDurrett I cannot find them either, so I can't edit them, but they're all white-list rules for inbound connections, none of them blocks traffic, only grant it. I tried finding those groups there, but no luck so far

Comment: I'm not sure. It kind of looks like you have an older version of the AWS console than the current one but I'm not sure if that is possible. Do you own the account and have rights on everything?

Comment: @BobbyDurrett I don't own it, but as far as I know I have access to everything. I've just realised a message appearing on the front page, I don't usually go there, but it seems you might be correct, as it's stating I'm missing a migration from the old EC2-Classic. It'll probably take a while, but I'll try to get back to you in case that's it. Thanks for your help